# What are arguments supporting "rapture" theory?

Tags: rapture, second-coming

By "rapture theory" I mean that coming of Christ happens in two phases with some time between "rapture" of the church and the coming itself.

In [an answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/29635/18955) to [my question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/29633/18955) it was mentioned that "rapture" theory is not the only considerable interpretation of Bible.

Before I thought that "rapture" theory is the only interpretation, but now I doubt.

To help me to decide on my theology, please list all Bible verses supporting "rapture theory". I also would like to hear arguments against this theory (but supporting coming of Christ in one "phase").

Comment: http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/revelation/related-topics/rapture-versus-second-coming.html present two parallel lists of verses, claiming that they describe these two different events

Comment: We do not answer Bible search questions. There are various study tools on the internet to aid you in your search. Also it is more desirable that you find those answers yourself as it it an aid to learning the Bible.

Comment: Perhaps consider rephrasing your question "What is the biblical basis for the rapture?"

Comment: http://www.openbible.info/topics/rapture

Comment: Please use the search bar to see if your question has already been asked before asking a new question.  If you think your question is substantially different from the questions I've linked, please edit your question to make that more clear.